locate in cron.daily not updating database
On a standard desktop installation of Ubuntu 24.04, when I try to use the locate command, searches for files that I clearly have in my home directory do not show up -- it appears as if the locate database has never been updated.
However, I can run sudo updatedb, which manually updates the locate database, and I can then search for files as expected. This continues to work for a day, after which searches for files in my home directory no longer work again. So my assumption is that after the locate script in cron.daily runs, the database is altered or erased.
One solution would be to just remove the locate script from cron.daily, which I think would "solve" the problem. But is there a more proper way to handle this?

In Ubuntu 22.04 with the default plocate (so likely in 24.04 as well) the /etc/cron.daily/plocate script simply exits if it detects systemd - the updating is nowadays handled via plocate-updatedb.service using a systemd timer.

@steeldriver It's still the issue that the user's locate database never updates though, so it seems their systemd service isn't triggering (that's half a statement and half a question).

@Kusalananda indeed - I didn't mean to imply otherwise, just that they probably needed to look elsewhere. AFAIK the plocate-updatedb.service just runs the same updatedb.plocate with the same /etc/updatedb.conf as executing updatedb manually - so the issue needs some deeper digging.

... perhaps a good place to start would be systemctl list-timers plocate-updatedb

This can be fixed by changing the line
LOCALUSER=nobody

in crond.daily into
LOCALUSER=root

I think this is safe since updatedb must be run as root anyway.
